# c# List does not return value "Object reference not set to an instance of an object "

Tags: c#, list

I get an error this error "object not set to an instance of an object" when i try to run this code in asp.net page

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Applications_Establishment_Test2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public class MYLIST
    {
        public string S_NUM;
        public string NAME_E;
        public string Dir;

        public MYLIST(string s_num, string name_e, string dir)
        {
            s_num = S_NUM;
            name_e = NAME_E;
            dir = Dir;
        }

    }

    public List<MYLIST> GetLista(string Snum)
    {
        List<MYLIST> UserInfo = new List<MYLIST>();

        UserInfo.Add(new MYLIST(Snum, "John", "HR"));

        return UserInfo;
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<MYLIST> UserInfo = GetLista("AB1234");
        MessageBox.Show(UserInfo[0].S_NUM.ToString());
    }
}
```

the error triggers when trying to read data fro list an display them in message box

MessageBox.Show(UserInfo[0].S_NUM.ToString());

can anyone help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you aren't initializing the fields of the class in the constructor but the parameter variables. For that reason the fields remain `null` which causes the `NullReferenceException`. So use this instead:

```
public class MYLIST
{
    public string S_NUM;
    public string NAME_E; 
    public string Dir;

    public MYLIST(string s_num, string name_e, string dir)
    {
        this.S_NUM = s_num;
        this.NAME_E = name_e;
        this.Dir = dir; 
    }
```

I always prepend `this.` to prevent this careless mistake.

Also, there is no `MessageBox` in ASP.NET, but you should [use the debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx) anyway.